# iOS: UTF8 Decoding problems with NSString

Tags: ios, sqlite, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a bug in my code when my query have characters like `'á', 'é', 'ñ'`...

I have to parse the NSString to "c string", and  characters like `"ñ"` are decoded to `"\xc3\xb1"`.

My code:

```
 NSString *querySchoolClass = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Select id FROM country where name like 'España';"];
 const char *queryEncoding = [querySchoolClass cStringUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I get no results with the query `"Select id FROM country where name like 'Espa\xc3\xb1a';"` because the table contains `"España"`. I am using SQLite with UTF-8.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stringWithUTF8String` like so:

```
NSString *querySchoolClass = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:@"Select id FROM country where name like 'Espa\xc3\xb1a';"];
```